# Help Identifying Touch Controller Chip

Tags: integrated-circuit, touch-panel

My oven started displaying an error code E11 that indicates a "shorted key".
These chips are on the back of the oven touch panel. They don't seem to be the Atmel chips. The marking on the SOT23-6 packages is B2PE.
Any info would be appreciated.

[image: Touch panel image]

Answer (score 1):

A [bit of hunting](http://www.mikrocontroller.net/topic/269764) finds that it's a TouchSensor TS-100.

Comment: Oh yeah I've seen this page before but stopped when some provided a link to the TC1015-2.7VCT713 in SOT23-5. I should've kept going. Thanks!

Comment: @Alex: I don't know much German, but I understand "nicht".